# Using std::function to store methods of inherited classes c++

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism, std

Is it possible to do something like this?:

```
// some_header.hpp
#ifndef SOME_HEADER_HPP
#define SOME_HEADER_HPP

class baseclass
{
public:
    baseclass(){};
    std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> methods_map;
    void call_method(const std::string &name){
        auto it = methods_map.find(name);
        if(it != methods_map.end())
            it->second();
        else std::cout << "Method " << name << " not exists";
    }
};
#endif
```

And than main.cpp

```
#include "some_header.hpp"

class inherited : public baseclass{
public:
   inherited():baseclass(){};   
   void new_meth(){
      std::cout << "Hello, stackoverflow!";
   }
};

int main(){
   std::vector<baseclass*> objects;
   auto temp = new inherited();
   objects[0].methods_map["new"]=&temp->new_meth;
   objects[0].call_method("new");
}
```

This varriant doesn't work, **Cannot create a non-constant pointer to member function**
So, my question: Is it possible to do smth like that and how?

Comment: Question: why you need inheritance here? This doesn't look like something is needed here. Maybe it would be better if you explain what kind of functionality you need to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close: `&temp->new_meth` isn't valid, you can capture `temp` into a `void()` functor through one of these ways:

```
objects[0]->methods_map["new"] = std::bind_front(&inherited::new_meth, temp);
```

```
objects[0]->methods_map["new"] = [&] { return temp->new_meth(); }
```

Notes:

- `objects[0]` is an invalid index since you never inserted anything into that vector;
- `objects[0]` is a pointer, so you need to dereference it with `->`;
- You should use `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw owning pointers.